# SQL Error [31] [08006]: ORA-00031: session marquée pour fermeture

Tags: sql, oracle, session

> ORA-00031: session marked for kill

I want Kill session Oracle, but his status it's KILLED but its RUNNING.
LOCK TYPE : Body Definition Lock

```sql
SELECT s.sid, l.lock_type, l.mode_held, l.mode_requested, l.lock_id1,
  'alter system kill session '''|| s.sid|| ','|| s.serial#||
  ''' immediate;' kill_sid
FROM dba_lock_internal l, v$session s
WHERE s.sid = l.session_id
  AND UPPER(l.lock_id1) LIKE '%PACKAGE_NAME%'
  AND l.lock_type = 'Body Definition Lock';`

alter system kill session 'SID, SERIAL' immediate;
```

Answer (score 1):

status `KILLED` means that it's been marked for kill, but it probably has some rollback to do before it disappears. When there is an open transaction and a session is killed, it's work has to be rolled back, and by default the session does that work itself. If the session itself were hard killed (via `disconnect immediate` or `kill -9` on the shadow process), then SMON would take over and perform the rollback as a fast-start transaction. That's not ideal, so generally speaking we want killed processes to complete the rollback themselves, and then they will disappear.

If you do get into a situation where you need their locks released immediately so you can compile a PL/SQL package they are using, you might then consider `alter session disconnect session .... immediate` or the `kill -9` on the `v$process.spid` on the server. But that shouldn't be a habit. Mistype the spid and you can down the database.

Before resorting to that, you can monitor `v$transaction.used_ublk` (join on `v$session.taddr = v$transaction.addr` and watch it drop - that's a rollback. When it hits zero the session should go away and release its locks. If you won't be waiting too long, I'd just wait.